# BigQuery Data Transfer - location not supported in command line, but works in GCP UI

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I was able to create data transfer in GCP UI from bucket in `europe-west3` location to BigQuery dataset which is also located in `europe-west3` zone.

When I try to do the same with `bq mk --transfer_config ...` command, I get an error:

```
BigQuery error in mk operation: BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: europe-west3
```

Where does this difference come from?

Comment: Can you confirm your --location is set to EU in command line  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference ?

Comment: `gcloud config list` shows `zone = europe-west3-a`.

Comment: I also tried to add --location=EU, but the error stays the same `BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: europe-west3`. 
As I understand It complains about bucket or dataset zone.

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider accepting :)

Comment: I get "BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: us" when attempting a data transfer using Python, but copying the dataset in the GCP UI works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the same problem and definitely this is not the expected behavior.
If you look in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/locations#supported_regions) (and in the image below), you'll see that this feature is not available in this specific region. The only regions available in Europe for Data Transfer are **europe-north1**, **europe-west2** and **europe-west6** Also, this region was never mentioned in any [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/release-notes).

[image]

Given that, I opened a ticket for your case in Issue Tracker (Google support channel).
You can find the progress in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160392465)